# Postgres SELECT query not using index

Tags: postgresql

I've created an index on a fairly large table of data (100 million + rows)

```
create index on web_responses_rebuild_2019_09 (response_time)
```

When I run an explain on a simple query of the data, it does not use the index, it does a full table scan

```
explain select *
from web_responses_rebuild_2019_09
where response_time between 1567398218
    and 1567398220;
```

Results:

```
QUERY PLAN
"Seq Scan on web_responses_rebuild_2019_09  (cost=10000000000.00..10044668761.32 rows=300 width=734)"
"  Filter: ((response_time >= 1567398218) AND (response_time <= 1567398220))"
```

...and we have a similarly named table and index that correctly does use the index.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain)

Comment: Does a `vacuum analyze web_responses_rebuild_2019_09;` change anything?

Comment: I tried the top suggestion adding analyze, but the query never returned, even disappeared from the list of executing queries... I'll try vacuum...

Comment: jjanes - I had simplified the select query for stack overflow - I have edited the query plan to match the SELECT * query

Comment: if you want to know why the query doesn't use the index, we need to whole query with the joins. It can impact why postgres is not using your index.

Comment: There are no joins. The query on this table, with this index, results in the shown query plan

Comment: Maybe the engine statuses that the query will be more effective with a sequence scan. This would occur if a large part of your table is between your boundaries. Could it be the case here?

Comment: I have done a little test on 9.6 version : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f927e6/1 All seems good for using the indexation if the engine considers it relevant.

Comment: An odd workaround that returns instantly is to change the BETWEEN range to:
WHERE response_time > 1565897045  LIMIT 1000;
...still doesn't use the index, but gets me the data I need instantly.

Comment: I think the simplest explanation is that you made a typo somewhere and either didn't build the index you think you built, or aren't querying the table you think you are querying.  If that isn't the case, then what does pg_index for this index show?  Do you have any odd settings for the costing parameters?  What if you simplify the WHERE to `response_time = 1567398220`?